# how to make functions to use in onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make 2 functions to use in onclick event.

The form I found in stackoverflow is something like this.

```
onclick={()=>{ f1(); f2() }}
```

I want to make f1() to show modal that has image in it.
Code I made is like this.

```
function f2() {
 setIsOpen(!isOpen);
 return(){
 <Modal isOpen={isOpen} >
   <div className='put_img'>
   <img src='img/img8.jpg' style={{ width: "100%" }} />
   </div>
 </Modal>
}}
```

and its not working. can help with this code? 
thank you

Comment: Returning a component from an event handler won’t do what you expect. Even if it did, you’re not returning anything from the anonymous click handler. The modal should be rendered all the time; its visibility is toggled by the `isOpen` property.

Answer (score 1):

You don't render elements in a click handler in React. Instead, you set a state member (which you seem to be doing) and in your main component function you use that state member to decide whether to render the thing you want to show.

So

```
const YourComponent = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const f1 = () => {
        // ...whatever f1 does...
    };

    const f2 = () => {
        setIsOpen(o => !o); // Generally best to use the callback version when setting based on existing state
    };

    // ...
    return (
        <YourOtnerStuff onClick={() => { f1(); f2(); }} />
        <Modal isOpen={isOpen} >
            <div className='put_img'>
                <img src='img/img8.jpg' style={{ width: "100%" }} />
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
};
```

When you set state, React will call your component function again to re-render. You'll get the value you set from `useState`.